# Mockito - when arrange with RxJava 2 .retry()

Tags: java, android, mockito, junit4

I'm trying to learn how to test methods with `.retry()`.

I have 2 basic classes:

```
public class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Completable execute() {
        return Completable.fromAction(() -> System.out.println("first part of task"))
                .andThen(bar.dangerousMethod()
                        .retry(10)
                )
                .andThen(Completable.fromAction(() -> System.out.println("sec part of task")));
    }
}


public interface Bar {
    Completable dangerousMethod();
}
```

Now I want to mock `dangerousMethod` to fail twice then emit `complete()`

```
@Mock private Bar bar;
@InjectMocks private Foo foo;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    when(bar.dangerousMethod()).thenReturn(
            error(new Exception()),
            error(new Exception()),
            complete()
    );

    foo.execute()
            .test()
            .assertComplete();
}
```

Unfortunately it fails:

> > first part of task
>
> java.lang.AssertionError: Not completed (latch = 0, values = 0, errors = 1, completions = 0)

and `dangerousMethod()` is **executed** 10 times but **run** only once, because of `.retry()` logic.

How to test the `.retry()` method using Mockito in a proper way?

Answer (score 3):

You should not test this method as it is not part of your code and it is (I hope) well tested by those guys who wrote RxJava library.

But anyway if you want to test that you can do it:

Replace your when statement with this:

```
   when(bar.dangerousMethod()).thenReturn(
                Completable.defer(new Callable<CompletableSource>() {
                    boolean fail = true;
                    @Override
                    public CompletableSource call() throws Exception {
                        if(fail) {
                            fail = false;
                            return Completable.error(new Exception());
                        } else {
                            return Completable.complete();
                        }
                    }
                }));
```

Comment: Ok - Maybe I didn't explain it well - I don't want to test `retry()` method. I want to check if my usecase is acting properly if some part of it fails few times. Your solution works, but its ugly like hell

Comment: In your code `dangerousMethod` is called only once, so there is no point to define what will be returned if it will be called more time which you define in `when(bar.dangerousMethod()).thenReturn(error(new Exception()),  error(new Exception()), complete());`. Defer is simple and clear in this case. If I will find anything more pretty I will let you know.